# Check the summary of spent money for Steam games

Tags: steam

How to check the all paid money in steam for paying games?

I mean the summary of spent money for paying games, i have a pretty bad feeling that i paid more than i think for the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your account in the upper right corner of Steam, and click on `Account Details` in the dropdown.

From there, click on the `STORE TRANSACTIONS` link to view your list of transactions.

[image]

I don't think it gives you a summary though, so you'll have to add up the total yourself.

Or as [FEichinger said below](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148565/check-the-summary-of-spent-money-for-steam-games#comment200605_148566), you can access it from the [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) extension.

<sub>(As a side note, wow I've really spent around $750 on steam games?! And that's just my account... boyfriend has his own account with roughly twice the games!)</sub>

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) extension offers this feature.

Comment: Thanks mates (ladies), i am sure i just saw the summary at sometime, and i maybe it is cleared: i think i have saw in the enchanced steam and not in the steam client. I will check it out now!

Comment: Echanced Steam just got it(y):
`Store Transactions:
0,00€
Game Transactions:
0,00€
Market Transactions:
260,43€
Total Spent:260,43€`
Rachel if you update your answer with enchanced steam (or FEichinger write another) i can accept it! Thanks!

Comment: @czupe Sure, its updated :)

Comment: @Rachell: Thanks, accepted it!
(For side note: this kind of wows make me also want to know how much i've spent:S)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that only a few days ago steam released a feature on its support page that allows you to see the sum of purchases: https://help.steampowered.com/en/accountdata/AccountSpend .

According to [this website](https://www.vg247.com/2018/06/20/steam-how-much-money-you-spent-games-market/):

> Old spend only shows the money spent up before April 17, 2015. You may remember that Valve instated a policy around that time that restricts users who have not spent at least $5 from trading, sending friend invites, or using the market.

which explains the distinction between the first two rows.

However:

> The total spend stat includes the old spend as well.

Regarding the last row the article states:

> As for PW spend, it’ll simply track all the money you spent through a Perfect World account in Dota 2, or Counter-Strike: Global Offensive. For anyone outside of China, this will most likely be $0, since it only tracks the Chinese versions of those games, which are co-published in the country by Perfect World.

This is how it would look like when visiting the linked support site: [image]

Answer (score 5):

[mysteamgauge.com](http://mysteamgauge.com) has a script that, when run on [store.steampowered.com/account](http://store.steampowered.com/account), will tell you the amount that you have spent within the Store (this does not include retail purchases)

To access the javascript you need to click on 'Receipt'. Then you simply need to follow the instructions found there.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken I think this gives you the current prices of your games.  I believe the OP wanted the price they paid.

Comment: I think you're mistaking the script I'm talking about with the actual Gauge. The gauge only requires you to login to Steam where it will then tell you how much your account is Worth, but not how much has actually been spent on it.

I'm talking about the javascript when you click on 'receipt'. Which if you then go to you account and run it, it will give you a total amount of money you have actually spent minus any credit (from market sales). It will also tell you how many of your purchases are actually from Steam and how many are from an external Store.

Comment: You are correct there.  I did not know Steam Gauge could do that.

Comment: Ok, also - i think good answer-, but Rachel and FEichiinger was faster a little bit (and i also checked out enchanced steam) so give them the accept mark, thanks mate anyway
(Now the mysteamgauge.com doesnt load in my browser:() Anyway voted up!